Tkinter by python doesn't work in Visual Studio Code, only in IDLE
I am a beginner developer and I've been trying to code some basic tkinter shapes. When I run it in the pyhon-mage ide called IDLE, there is no problem. However, when I try to run it in Visual Studio Code, no window opens up. There is nothing written in console (only PS C:\Users\maria> & C:/Users/maria/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/maria/Desktop/Untitled-3.py)...
Can anybody help me please?
I expected to run the code in Visual Studio Code as well, not only in IDLE, but it doesn't work.
Here is the code:
import tkinter, random
canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "purple", "pink"]
for i in range(20):
    x = random.randint(10,300)
    y = random.randint(10, 200)
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+random.randint(5, 50), y+random.randint(5, 50), fill = colors[random.randint(0, len(colors)-2)])

This is what IDLE displays (this is what I want):

And this is what visual studio displays (nothing is displayed):


Try adding canvas.mainloop() at the end of the code. The problem is that there is nothing stopping python from finishing code execution and exiting in VSCode (with your set up). The canvas.mainloop() will tell tkinter to keep updating the GUI until all windows are closed.

@TheLizzard thank you so much for answering, it works now!!!

But why did it work with IDLE without canvas.mainloop()?

IDLE runs python with the -i command line argument. That is why you can execute python commands after the code has finished running. It also updates tkinter while waiting for the user input

Now it makes sense! Thank you! @TheLizzard

I know this is pedantic, but in order to avoid confusion: Visual Studio != Visual Studio Code (yes, the branding is confusing - thanks Microsoft!)
